# Understanding merge in rxjs6 (and redux-observable specifically)

Tags: merge, redux-observable, rxjs6

**Context**: I'm trying to use `redux-observable` with `rxjs v6` to trigger multiple actions after fetching a resource.

**Problem**: I can trigger a single action after fetching the resource no problem; but my attempt to trigger multiple actions has me stumped. Specifically, my attempt shown below to use rxjs `merge` to trigger multiple actions seems so standard and close to documented examples ([see e.g. here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html)) that I can't understand where I'm going wrong. Here is a breakdown of my code with typescript types indicated in comments; I've simplified things for the sake of problem clarity:

```
import { from } from "rxjs"; 
import { merge, mergeMap, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { AnyAction } from "redux";

... //Setup related to rxjs-observable epics

function myEpic(
    action$: Observable<AnyAction>,
    state$: any,
    {fetchPromisedStrings}: any
) {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType('MY_ACTION'),
        mergeMap(
            action => 
{
    const demoAction1: AnyAction = {type:'FOO1', payload:'BAR1'};
    const demoAction2: AnyAction = {type:'FOO2', payload:'BAR2'};

    const w = from(fetchPromisedStrings())     //const w: Observable<string[]>
    const x = w.pipe( map(() => demoAction1)); //const x: Observable<AnyAction> 
    const y = w.pipe( map(() => demoAction2)); //const y: Observable<AnyAction> 

    //My attempt to merge observables:
    const z = merge(x,y); // const z: OperatorFunction<{}, {} | AnyAction>

    // return x; // Works :)
    // return y; // Works :)
    return z;    // Doesn't work :(
}   
        )
    );
}
```

This code gives me the following error when I try to `return z`:

```
TypeError: You provided 'function (source) { return source.lift.call(_observable_merge__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["merge"].apply(void 0, [source].concat(observables))); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable
```

So what's the problem here? I'd expect `merge` in the above code to take the two `Observable<AnyAction>` types and return a single `Observable<AnyAction>` type (or some more general type that's compatible with `Observable<AnyAction>`, which my epic needs in order to function correctly). Instead, I get some opaque type called `OperatorFunction<{}, {} | AnyAction>` that, evidently, isn't compatible with `Observable<AnyAction>`. Could someone please unmuddle my thinking here? Is `merge` not the operator I am supposed to use here, or is my entire `rxjs-v6` pattern wrong for the (seemingly) simple goal of triggering multiple actions after fetching a promised resource?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is ok, but you've imported [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge) operator instead of [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge) observable factory

Just do:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Agghh! Thanks so much!

Comment: Came over to say this helped me out on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621370/fire-multiple-actions-and-wait-for-them-to-resolve-rxjs-redux-observables/54631116#54631116. I spent ages trying to work out why it wasn't working and it was all down to an import so thanks!!

Comment: Just had the same issue with the `concat` as an operator instead of a factory... Thanks!